# Deploy a html file on tomcat which gets created after deploying a war

Tags: java, spring

I have a dynamic web-app. I'm working in a spring environment, with maven and mybatis. I'm deploying a war file on tomcat.  I'm using log4j for logging the data. I want this data to be accessible real time to everyone. For example if the home page of the web-app is `localhost:8080` then I want something like localhost:8080/logs to display the logs real time. I know I have to Spring request mapping for this. But I don't know how to make it work, when my file keeps on updating itself.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you thinking @RequestMapping("errLog.log") then it just reads the log file and dumps it to response.getOutputStream()? I guess im confused with the question, do you need help getting your mappings working or using the mappings/servlet to output the log file.

Comment: @ns47732, Thank you for your response. I need help with using mapping/servlet to output the log file to a webpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a spring mvc. 
In your controller, you need to read the file and write it into the response. 
It's actually fair simple.

Code snippet for you as reference: The following is SUDO code. Just give you the direction

@RequestMapping("/log")
public class Controller {

```
public void readLog(HttpRequest req, HttpResponse resp) {

    File file = new File('YOUR_FILE_LOCATION')

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);


    // you can read every line for the log file and write into resposne
    while(str = nextLine()) {
        resp.println(str)
    }

    fr.close()  

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML Layout feature of log4j as following:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${catalina.base}/webapps/yourappname/log.html

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.Title=HTML logs
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.LocationInfo=true
```

This file should be accessible on `http://localhost:8080/yourappname/log.html`. Tomcat will provide catalina.base/catalina.home as system property or you can provide full file path.